# Why not Eclipse for rails development over Sublime text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, sublimetext2

I requested to buy [Sublime text editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/) in my office for commercial use. But they are asking why don't I use Eclipse for rails development in Ubuntu.
Well, I am habitual of using Sublime text editor since last 2 years. So, I don't want to switch any other editor as it would affect my consistency and work efficiency as well. But He want some perfect reason to buy.

Anyone can say Why not Eclipse for rails development over Sublime text?

One reason I can say Sublime takes very less Memory and run faster than Eclipse.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: You might have better luck for this on forums that are more open to discussion/opinion - offhand, I'm not sure where would be most appropriate.  I'll throw my opinion on as an answer, it may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an easy thing to argue for purchasing something when your office has free software to do the job.

When I've had to do this, I've broken it down into percentage productivity increase (say even a conservative small number like 2% - which is about 10 minutes per workday), and apply that to your wage, showing how long it will take for the purchase to be worth it.

For example, say you earn $5000/month - 2% productivity gain works out to $100, meaning that if the purchase is under $100, it's already paid for itself by the end of the first month.  This benefit can increase a lot if multiple people will take advantage of the purchase for similar productivity gains.

As you can see, it's usually a very short timeframe for things like this. Breaking down a purchase into cost/benefit and showing the raw numbers usually makes things like this incredibly clear.